# Unknown column in fieldlist error when joining tables

Tags: mysql

can someone please help me fix this query. Whenever I run it I keep getting the unknown fieldlist error.

```
SELECT 
 busline.line_id,
 plz.city AS startpoint,
 plz.city AS endpoint
FROM 
 busline
INNER JOIN
 plz as sp ON buslinie.startstation = sp.plz_id 
INNER JOIN 
 plz as ep ON buslinie.endstation = ep.plz_id
```

Comment: the joind tables have a new alias and have to be addressed as sp and ep

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 bl.line_id,
 sp.city AS startpoint,
 ep.city AS endpoint
FROM 
 busline bl
INNER JOIN
 plz as sp ON bl.startstation = sp.plz_id 
INNER JOIN 
 plz as ep ON bl.endstation = ep.plz_id
```